# Does the IPFS JavaScript client support stream (chunked) uploads?

Tags: ipfs, js-ipfs

Is there a way to upload a file to IPFS chunk-by-chunk using the js-ipfs-http-client package? To improve the concurrency model of my application, I’d like to avoid holding complete files in memory and instead just work with the chunks.

In the source, I can see a method called `start` is not implemented. Is this supposed to enable this behavior in the long run?

I asked this [question](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/does-the-ipfs-javascript-client-support-stream-uploads/14427) on discuss.ipfs.io as well a little while back.